# AWK throwing "runaway string constant" error in jenkins

Tags: awk

I am trying to parse the output return but AWS athena command to get the `QueryExecutionId`  from the request result using AWK. Below is my command, this command works fine on Macbook terminal but keeps of throwing below error on jenkins. I am sure its related to the type of shell in both the environment but not an expert on it to understand how below command will be different in jenkins.

```
#!/bin/sh
result=$(aws athena start-query-execution --query-string "$sql" --result-configuration "OutputLocation=s3://s3_bucket/athena/")
ID=$(echo $result | awk  'BEGIN{FS="\""}{print $4}')
```

```
+ result={
    "QueryExecutionId": "5c7464fa-b23d-421b-b9cb-ez14f1742b1"
}
+ echo { "QueryExecutionId": "5c7464fa-b23d-421b-b9cb-ez14f1742b1" }
+ awk BEGIN{FS="""}{print $4}
awk: line 1: runaway string constant "}{print $4 ...
+ ID=
```

Comment: Looks like something's eating the backslash to escape the quote in FS.

Comment: does `awk -F'"' '{print $4}'` work? do you have `bash` available on both hosts and if so what happens if you update the shebang to reference `bash`?

Comment: Why is tracing turned on in the code? I don't see any `set -x` between the `#!` (hash bang) line and the two assignment comments in the script shown. This could be a case of showing one version of the code in the question, but the output of a different version of the code.